# How to implement class relationship between two classes where one class can perform all functions of another class but actually is not a subclass?

Tags: class, oop, inheritance, uml, class-diagram

I'm creating a student information system which will have two access levels namely admin and manager. The `Admin` class can perform all functions of `Manager` class along with some additional functions. But literally speaking an Admin is not a manager. So how should I implement this relationship? Is it okay to do `Admin extends Manager` or is there any other way to implement this? (I'll be using java to implement the system)

Answer (score 3):

Well, UML provides 3 mechanisms to depict (some) similarity between classes.

1. Generalization
2. Interfaces
3. Substitution

Let's look at them closer:

### Generalization

When two classes are in generalization relationship, one of them (subclass, specialized or child class) is a kind of the other (superclass, general or parent class). Child class has all attributes and methods of its parents (inherits them) and can have some additional attributes or methods and can handle some methods in a different matter.
Generalization is depicted with a solid line and an arrow whose head is an empty triangle. Head is pointing the more general class

### Interfaces

Actually interfaces are not a direct relationship between two classes that are in some way similar. But they help to show it to some degree.
Interface is a specific kind of a class that has a collection of methods. Interface is not directly instantiated, but other classes can either realize the interface or require an interface.
If a class realizes an interface (or provides it in other words) then it has to have all the methods of an interface, however interface in no way enforces a method of implementation.
So we may have two (or more) classes that realize the same interface and then both those classes will be able to perform the same functions, however it might be a totally different way.
We show interface realization by a dashed line and an arrow in a form of empty triangle, pointing the interface.
The class that requires the interface is the class interacting with those classes providing the interface.
To show interface usage you use a dashed line with an open arrow and stereotype `<<use>>` (well, technically it is not a stereotype).

### Substitution

Class substitution is used to shown that one class can step into the role of the other class but it is not a kind of that class. A substituting class has to have all methods of the class it substitutes but it might have different internal representation.
This relationship is used when two or more classes can perform similar roles but they are not of the same kind.
Substitution relationship is shown as a dashed line with an open arrowhead pointing the class that can be substituted and a stereotype `<<substitute>>`

Your case is substitution, where Admin can substitute Manager, however you can combine substitution with interfaces to make it clearer.
Also always make sure that the recipient of your documentation will understand the element models you're going to use.

Comment: I was not aware about <<substitute>> but how do you implement it ? in the norm, it is cited with template.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a parent class with the methods shared by both Admin and Manager.

Comment: Yeah. I can create an abstract class `ManagementUse`r and extend `Manager` and `Admin` from it. My doubt is the `Manager` class will not have extra attributes or behaviors. Is it okay to just extend an abstract class and use it as it is? I'm new to OOP. I want to know the right practices.

Comment: Making the abstract class makes things more clear, and also allow you make future changes to one without having to chance the other. It also doesn't make much sense to have a parent classe with less "permissions" than it's child - in this particular case.

Comment: What do you mean by _It also doesn't make much sense to have a parent classe with less "permissions" than it's child - in this particular case._?

Comment: I mean literally what i said. It's like saying a leopard extends a cat just because they can do the same thing. Things get way clearer when you put the felin class above them.

Comment: I get it. I have one more doubt. If all feline eats and jump in the same way, can I declare feline class as non-abstract class and define the methods inside feline class itself? If I declare feline class as Abstract then I will have to define the abstract methods in the same way in leopard and cat class.

Comment: If you want to be able to create a feline object then make it a concrete class. If every class that inherits feline has unique implementations of the same methods, you can make feline an interface. Now if just some of feline's methods will have different implementations, you can make feline as an anstract class and override the methods that must be different among the classes that inherit feline. You should never make a class concrete If you won't make instances of It.

Comment: I am not sure that saying "admin is not a manager" is true. I mean this true literaly speaking but if in your model amdin should be able to do all what a manager does, it means that an admin is a sort of manager no ? The point is if you get also others sorts of users you will be block because multi-inheritance is often a bad practice. Why can't you use Adaptors ? One Adaptor which can all methods used by Admin and then Admin call this Adaptor ? Delegation is often a solution when generalization failed. Or you can set Admin as a template classe with Manager as T.